# Почему приложение поворачивается вертикально, если в манифесте это отключено?

Tags: android, orientation

Клиент обратился с проблемой, в которой по каким-то неведомым причинам приложение поворачивается вертикально *(хотя в манифесте это отключено)*, а при повороте горизонтально картинка не растягивается во весь экран.

За пол года ничего подобного не получал от клиентов.

В манифесте отключаю вертикальный поворот этой волшебной строчкой: `android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"`

К сожалению нет видео этой проблемы или даже скриншотов, но со слов очевидцев это должно выглядеть так:

**Вертикальная ориентация:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Горизонтальная ориентация:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Телефон, на котором случилось это чудо: **хуавей g-700u10**

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным? Кто знает как помочь людям с такими устройствами?

**Код манифеста:**

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
>
> <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
>     android:banner="@drawable/banner" >
>     <activity
>         android:name="package.MainActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name"
>         android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
>         android:launchMode="singleTask"
>         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
>         >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
>             <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />-->
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
> </application>
>
> <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback"
>     android:required="false"
>     tools:ignore="ManifestOrder" /> <!-- false - работает на всех устройствах, true - только на устройствах с интерфейсом Leanback -->
> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
>     android:required="false" /> <!-- заявляем, что сенсорный экран не трубется -->
> ```

Comment: код манифеста в студию

Comment: @MartinezToni, спасибо за ответ. Код манифеста добавил к вопросу.

Answer (score 0):

Замените         android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" на android:screenorientation="landscape"

sensorLandscape - альбомная ориентация, но может быть как нормальной, так и обратной, в зависимости от датчика устройства.

Comment: Наверное android:screenorientation="landscape"? Почему я не могу использовать "sensorLandscape"?

Comment: @ДмитрийЧубаров поправил

Comment: Просто у меня на телефоне он вертикально не поворачивается, а поворачивается только горизонтально. Если же я поставлю "landscape", то он будет всегда горизонтально в одном положении и не будет меняться вообще никак, а с "sensorLandscape" хотя бы можно горизонталь сменить... Просто вертикальная ориентация тут все равно ведь отключена